# Supremum and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis

I've read in a book of Faries (called: Self-adjoint Opertors) the following statement: Given an inner product, it satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$|\langle f,g \rangle | \leq \|f \| \|g \|.$$ This means that the norm of g, $\|g\|$, can be computed as the supremum of $|\langle f,g \rangle|$, with $\|f\| \leq 1$. So this is a first question. A second question is:
I really don't understand that first question above for one reason. The fact is that I know the definition of sup, but I don't understand it's real significance or even when do I have to use it, that is, how a mathematician think about "*pass the supremum*".
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is
$$\|g\| = \sup_{f:\|f\| \le 1} |\langle f,g\rangle |.$$

---

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows that $\|g\|$ us an upper bound for $|\langle f,g\rangle|$ for any $f$ satisfying $\|f\| \le 1$.
Thus,
$$\|g\| \ge \sup_{f:\|f\| \le 1} |\langle f,g\rangle |.$$
To show the reverse inequality, take $f := g/\|g\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see. By your text, I can say that if something (let's say A) is an upper bound for another (say B) then A=sup B. Right?

Comment: @R.Ferreira No, $\sup B$ is the *least* upper bound. If $A$ is an upper bound, then all you can say is $A \ge \sup B$ (which is the first step in my proof). To show equality you need to show that it is the *least* upper bound, which is the second step of my proof.

Comment: Now I got the idea! Thanks once more!