# Should be $\sup_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, y \rangle\ = ||x||$ or $\sup_{||y|| = 1} |\langle x, y \rangle | = ||x||$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the following posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267660/supremum-and-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295407/norm-is-sup-of-inner-products-proof) where the equalities
$\sup_{||y|| = 1} |\langle x, y \rangle | = ||x||$ and $\sup_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, y \rangle\ = ||x||$ appear, respectively. Another related posts are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383973/does-fracxx-maximize-inner-product-with-x-among-vectors-of-norm-1?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864018/proving-inner-product-space-induced-norm-property).

I am little confused about if we need the absolute value or not in the sup. If we use the left hand side of the inequality $\langle x, y \rangle \leq |\langle x, y \rangle|$ I think we can end up in the no absolute value version. Whereas if we use the right hand side of $\langle x, y \rangle \leq |\langle x, y \rangle|$ we have the absolute value version.

But which is more correct? After all, do we the absolute value in sup or not?

Comment: I assume you work over $\mathbb{R}$? It doesn't really matter, both expressions are equal. Try to prove it.

Comment: It's equivalent, since $\langle x, y \rangle \le \lvert\langle x, y \rangle\rvert$ and because of the symmetry of the constraint on $y$ - for all $y$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle < 0$, you can look at $-y$ and $\langle x, -y \rangle > 0$.

Comment: @Mark yes in $\mathbb{R}$. Can you provide a little more guidance?

Comment: @Thoth Clearly $\langle x,y\rangle\leq |\langle x,y\rangle|$. Also, $|\langle x,y\rangle|$ is equal either to $\langle x,y\rangle$ or to $\langle x,-y\rangle$. From these two facts it's not hard to prove that the two supremums are equal.

Comment: @Mark can you provide the correct facts? Sorry but I can not see them.

Comment: @Thoth Where exactly is the problem? Which of the two things I wrote is unclear?

Comment: @Mark sorry. You are just saying that we can use the part of $|\langle x,y\rangle|$ that equals $\langle x,y\rangle$ ans we are done? Also, if we use the other part $\langle x,-y\rangle$, this means that $\sup_{||y|| = 1} |\langle x, y \rangle |= \sup_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, y \rangle =  \sup_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, -y \rangle = -\sup_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, y \rangle = \inf_{||y|| = 1} \langle x, y \rangle $?

Comment: @Thoth No, that's not what I mean. Let $A=\{\langle x,y\rangle: ||y||=1\}$ and $B=\{|\langle x,y\rangle|: ||y||=1\}$. A general element in $B$ has the form $|\langle x,y\rangle|$. Since it is equal to $\langle x,y\rangle$ or to $\langle x,-y\rangle$, this shows this element also belongs to $A$, in either case. So $B\subseteq A$, and I hope you can prove that this implies $\sup(B)\leq\sup(A)$. Conversely, each element of $A$ satisfies $\langle x,y\rangle\leq |\langle x,y\rangle|\leq\sup(B)$. So $\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A$, thus $\sup(A)\leq\sup(B)$.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the comment. You can also place it as an answer to accept it. The only think that I am not sure is why $\langle x, -y \rangle \in A$. Is that because with a change of variable we have

$$A=\{\langle x,y\rangle: ||y||=1\} \equiv \{\langle x,-y\rangle: ||-y||=1\} \equiv \{\langle x,-y\rangle: ||y||=1\}$$

which implies $\langle x, -y\rangle \in  \{\langle x,-y\rangle: ||y||=1\}$ ? I am not sure  of accepting the above equivalence after the change of variable.

Comment: @Thoth There is no change of variable here. We have one specific element which we want to show belongs to $A$. An element of $A$ is by definition an element of the form $\langle x,z\rangle$ where $||z||=1$. Given that $||y||=1$, is $\langle x,-y\rangle$ an element of this form? Yes, because if $||y||=1$ then $||-y||=1$ as well. And yeah, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{⟨x,y⟩:||y||=1\}$ and $B=\{|⟨x,y⟩|:||y||=1\}$. A general element in $B$ has the form $|⟨x,y⟩|$. Since it is equal to $⟨x,y⟩$ or to $⟨x,−y⟩$, this shows this element also belongs to $A$, in either case. So $B⊆A$, and it's a standard exercise that this implies $\sup(B)≤\sup(A)$. Conversely, each element of $A$ satisfies $⟨x,y⟩≤|⟨x,y⟩|≤\sup(B)$. So $\sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A$, and hence $\sup(A)≤\sup(B)$.

Comment: Please let me ask something last. Is there any practical reason to have this equivalence? Do we apply the one with the absolute value or the other depending on the application? For example, in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082880/are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-and-just-its-diagonal-related/3094611#comment10236859_3094611), `@Undertherainbow`'s answer, we use the absolute value version in order to use it later when we need to deal with the spectral norm of the diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Thoth Yes, depending on what we need. I believe it's much more common with absolute value. This way it also works over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion.